# Regular Expression, get text between "+" and end of the line in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have something like below and need to extract all the text between "+" and the end of line.

```
+  context: projectRoot,
+  entry: path.resolve(projectRoot, 'src/scripts/Index'),
+
+  resolve: {
+    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
+  };
module: {
+    loaders: [{
+      test: /\.jsx?$/,
+      exclude: /node_modules/,
+      loader: 'babel?presets[]=stage-0,presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015',
   },
+
+  output: {
+    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
+    publicPath: deploymentBuild ? config.build.assetsPublicPath : config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
+    filename: '[name].js',
+  },
```

i want to extract each and every line start with the "+" and ignore other lines.

Help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Edit : 2

```
String codeDiff = "";
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DiffFormatter df = new DiffFormatter(baos);
        df.setRepository(git.getRepository()); // get repo
        List<String> diffCodes = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> packageChangesArray = new ArrayList<>(); // plus and minus changes from package json
        for (DiffEntry entry : diffs) { //loop
            df.format(df.toFileHeader(entry));
            diffCodes.add(new String(baos.toByteArray()));
            codeDiff = new String(baos.toByteArray());
            Pattern p  = Pattern.compile("(\\+)(.*)(,)" ,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(codeDiff);
            while (m.find()){
                String c1=m.group(1);
//                String c2=m.group(2);
                System.out.print("("+c1.toString()+")"+"("+")"+"\n");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use ctrl-k to highlight code or literal input

Comment: so are you reading your contents from a file, standard output, string or from where? a java question related to help with code should have at least some code in it. also, why regular expressions, can't you just iterate the lines and do indexOf +  substring?

Comment: thanks. i actually have a byte array which i took from a git commit file. i want to get the (+) s and (-) s separately. Edit 1 : i have added the part of String .

Comment: Line `+++ b/.eslintrc` fits your requirement. Did you want that line?

Comment: +      "no-undef": "error", < - this my requirement.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ Question reads as "I'm don't know regex, so please write it for me". If you don't know regex, then now is a great time to learn. If you do know regex, then show what you've tried.

Comment: bro i actually know some regex and did few stuff. i am having problem cus the text between "+" and the end line is totally random. im getting stuff from git. so some times its json, sometimes its HTML. I just want to extract the text ( don't know the format because its random) between "+" and the end of line.

Comment: Using regex, findall  `(?m)^\+(.*)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get these lines from a git commit file, you can use following.

```
try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("path to your file")) {
    List<String> collect = lines
            .filter(s -> s.startsWith("+"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```